# Is there a way to get index of last character in the string

Tags: java, string

I need to insert a String in between a String, is there a better way of doing it, currently I am doing like below which works fine, but I dont want to add **+ 13**.

```
String query = "Create table asdas aaa (int(5), bbb varchar2(20));";

    int i = query.toLowerCase().indexOf("create table");
    int lengthOfCreateTable = 13;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(query);
    if(i != -1)
    {
        StringBuilder appendStr = new StringBuilder().append("'").append(db).append("'").append(".");
        sb.insert(i + lengthOfCreateTable,  appendStr);
    }
```

Comment: What does 13 mean? Is it `"create table".length()`? If so, then do that.

Comment: Title: "get index of last character in the string" -> `string.length()-1` - but I do not understand how the title is related to the question

Comment: Also, be very careful about building SQL statements in a string by manually appending strings together. This potentially makes your code vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. Where does the value of `db` come from? If the user can enter anything they want here, then then can add any code they want to your query, such as drop table, insert any data they want, etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear; please show variable input and desired output.

Comment: I don't get it. Can anyone create a table in your case? Is the `CREATE TABLE` statement auto-generated? Are the table and field names variables or something? If not...just fix your SQL string instead of writing code to do that for you. If so...then fix the code that generates the SQL String to ensure table and field names are handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

1. Yes, there is a simple way to insert a string within a string
2. No, you generally should **NOT** use string concatenation or the options provided for solving *(1)* when you create a database query and use user provided data to build this query because that is a serious security issue as it makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). You can e.g. use [`PreparedStatement`s](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-preparedstatement-in-java/) in Java to solve that issue.

### Insert string

Here you have a couple of options:

> This is not an exhaustive list, but covers the most important/ common ways to do this.

#### Concatenation

```java
String myName = "John";
System.out.println("My name is " + myName + " and I welcome you!"); // My name is John and I welcome you!
```

#### [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) (since Java 1.5)

```java
String myName = "John";
System.out.println(String.format("My name is %s and I welcome you!", myName)); // My name is John and I welcome you!
```

You can actually in this case use `System.out.printf()` to combine those two calls (You need to add a new line though using `%n` or `\n`):

```java
String myName = "John";
System.out.printf("My name is %s and I welcome you!%n", myName); // My name is John and I welcome you!
```

#### [`.formatted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) (since Java 15)

```java
String myName = "John";
System.out.println("My name is %s and I welcome you!".formatted(myName)); // My name is John and I welcome you!
```

#### [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) (since Java 1.5)

Here you can use an [`Appendable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Appendable.html) (and others) which makes it possible to use a `StringBuilder` and append many formatted strings.

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
String myName = "John";
int myAge = 43;
formatter.format("My name is %s. ", myName);
formatter.format("I am %d years old.", myAge);
System.out.println(sb); // My name is John. I am 43 years old
```

Generally it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with [format specifiers](https://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm).

### Building a SQL query

The aforementioned options should generally not be used to create SQL queries using user provided data as this will make your application vulnerable to SQL injection.

Please head over to [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) and read through the description and examples of SQL injection attacks so you get an understanding of why that's vital. It's fairly simple to understand but also very simple to perform the attack, that's why you will almost certainly be exposed to it (if your software is out in the world of course).

However, the good news is, it's also easy to prevent an successful attack using prepared statements like e.g.

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("replace with valid URL to database");
String customerId = "x123";
String query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM customers WHERE id = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
// provide position (1-based) and value you want to have instead of ?
pstmt.setString(1, customerId);
ResultSet results = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

> You will need to add some error/ exception handling which I left out by reason of brevity.

> **Important**: Performing a SQL attack is **illegal**, so don't just go visit websites and check whether they`re vulnerable to SQL injection. Use your own local progams/ sites or [OWASP WebGoat](https://owasp.org/www-project-webgoat/) which is specifically created for this purpose.

#### Edit:

As outlined in the comments one limitation is that you cannot use `PreparedStatment`s for column names or table names, so how to work around that?

First, let me start by saying that there is one important detail I was missing, which is obvious though. You can only have a SQL injection when the value is supplied by an malicious user, therefore if you can guarantee that the query can be created without user input you can use string concatenation and you should be fine.

However, I personally wouldn't trust that, since you have to trust e.g. your fellow colleagues to use a method like `public ResultSet selectFromColumn(String columnName)` correctly (without the `columnName` being supplied by a user). So the only option you have left is to validate yourself.

One option here would be **whitelisting** i. e. have a list of valid column names that can safely be used. Typically database systems have a table which stores metadata information about schemas and tables (e.g. `information_schema.tables` in Postgres), so it's easy to get all valid column names of a table and check against these.

Of course it also helps if your database user is setup properly following the [Need to know principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_to_know) and you have suffient logging as well as authentication and authorization setup properly.

Last but not least, it all depends on your application. Is it gonna be publicly exposed? Who are going to be the users? What's the purpose of the application? If it's for a simple application that should help students learn SQL a well setup database user is probably enough as you want students to be able to mess around with the data in the database system, but maybe do not give them administrative privileges or access to system-relevant tables.

Comment: but will `PreaparedStatement` placeholders also work for schema (database) name? (as being done in questions code) It does not work for the table or for column names

Comment: You can use a _[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)_ instance also.

Comment: I've updated my answer and included `Formatter` and some suggestions regarding placeholders for database names and columns.

Comment: I've adjusted the wording ;)